# How to remove white space and space before comma in a php variable?

Tags: php, preg-replace

Is it possible to combine both these lines of code into one? 
Thanks

```
$address = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $address); /*remove extra whitespace */
$address = preg_replace('/\s*,/', ',', $address); /* remove spaces before a comma */
```

Solution:

```
$address = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/\s*,/'), array(' ', ','), $address);
```

Or as Kelly suggested below:

```
$search = array('/\s{2,}/', '/\s*,/');
$replace = array(' ', ',');

$addresses = preg_replace($search, $replace, $addresses);
```

Comment: $address = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/\s*,/'), array(' ', ','), $address);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace` also accepts arrays as its first three arguments. Check out the example below.

```
$search = [
    '/\s{2,}/',
    '/\s*,/'
];

$replace = [
    ' ',
    ','
];

$string = "This string    needs some  fixing upping , man.";

$fixedString = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);

echo $fixedString;
```

This little script should print out:

```
This string needs some fixing upping, man.
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get the array to work as you wrote it but used the solution above... Is it possible to define an array like that?  $array = ['foo','bar'];

Comment: Nice. It could be the PHP version. The short array syntax used in my example was added in 5.4 ([example #1 in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php))

Comment: Yes it was a php version issue. I'm using 5.3.22